# Count the number of months between two dates

Tags: php, date

Let's assume I have two dates in variables, like :

```
$dateFrom = '2021/07/20';
$dateTo = '2021/08/10';
```

I did that but it still doesn't get results:

```
$from = new \DateTime($dateFrom);
$to = new \DateTime($dateTo);

$interval = $to->diff($from);

$a = $interval->format('%m months');
dd($a); // result : 0 months
```

I need to calculate the number of months between `$dateFrom` and `$dateTo`. I need to get `2`.
Is there any way to get it?

Thanks

**update:** Mine is less than 60 days, less than 2 months. But how to complete 2 months

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: @Rahul_Mandhane I've seen this post..but it only got full month. It counts as 30 days as a month. Time I need to get the month by number of day but not enough 30 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you:

```
    $dateFrom = '2021/07/20'; // Suppose dateFrom is older than dateTo
    $dateTo = '2021/08/10';
    $from = new DateTime($dateFrom);
    $to = new DateTime($dateTo);
    
    $monthsDiff = $to->format('m') - $from->format('m');
    $yearsDiff = $to->format('Y') - $from->format('Y');
    if ($monthsDiff < 0){
       $yearsDiff = $yearsDiff - 1;
    }
    echo ((($monthsDiff + 12) % 12) + 1) + $yearsDiff * 12;
```

Comment: That's great.Thank you for helping me with my work

Answer (score 1):

u can use DateTime

```
$dateFrom = new DateTime('2021-07-20');
$dateTo = new DateTime('2021-08-10');

$interval = $dateTo->diff($dateFrom);

$interval->format('%m months');
```

Comment: Thank you. But if my date is two strings, how should I handle it? `$dateFrom = '2021/07/20';`  `$dateTo = '2021/08/10';`

Comment: @Miedkes, new DateTime(string of date) => new DateTime(2021-07-20), u need to transfer the string to the constructor of this object

Comment: The result when i follow you it returns 0.I edited the question.Can you help me

Comment: @Miedkes oh my god, it's not about the format, this format works too! count how many days are the difference between the dates? 21 day! therefore month 0

Comment: Yes. I converted it, but the result is still 0 months . `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateTo));`

Comment: @Miedkes count days

Comment: Thank you. But I for example..dateFrom = "2021-07-01" and dateTo= "2021-08-30" I get is two months. But when $dateFrom = "2021-07-20" and $dateTo = "2021-08-10" it gets a month. But I want to get two months, that is July and August. So what to do?

Comment: @Miedkes , oh, ping me in telegram - tberendakova